# Sql. table, data e horário organizado

Tags: sql, android-studio, datetime, timepicker

Eu tenho uma tabela sql que vai conter compromisso, data e horário. eu guardo os três baseados no ID.
Estou com uma dúvida em relação a data e o horário

> ```
> id = 0; data 28/08/2018 - 13:11h
> id = 1; data 26/08/2018 - 17:10h
> id = 2; data 25/08/2018 - 11:15h
> ```

Eu quero organizar a tabela desta forma:

> ```
> id = 0; data 25/08/2018 - 11:15h
> id = 1; data 26/08/2018 - 17:10h
> id = 2; data 28/08/2018 - 13:11h
> ```

Pois quando eu agendar um horário e um data, eu poderia ter uma noção para setar o próximo alarme baseado no id 0. Estou com problemas em relação a isto, pois quando eu salvo uma data e um horário, eu não sei qual chamar

Comment: Não percebi a sua questão... o horário não está associado a um ID específico? Como é que pretende organizar os horários por IDs diferentes?

Comment: Na verdade eu queria colocar as datas na forma DESC na tabela, para que a data sempre ficasse perto da data atual, como fazer isso?

Comment: ao invés de alterar o id, porque você não cria um campo pra _ordem de exibição_?

Comment: Poderia exemplificar? estou com dúvida sobre como fazer isso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que você precisa de uma consulta SQL como você mesmo descreveu com o DESC no campo "data":

```
SELECT * FROM nome_da_tabela ORDER BY data DESC
```

Mas pelo que percebi você quer dar um update na linha para trocar a ID de acordo com a data, é isto? . Se for, não aconselho fazer isso diretamente na tabela de banco de dados e sim de forma programática com um loop acrescentando uma nova coluna e identificando a ordem (0,1,2,etc...), ou até mesmo mudando a regra de negócio para utilizar a consulta ordenada pela data.

Espero que ajude!

Abraço, Herbert.

Comment: Mudando a regra de negócio, como eu faria o SELECT na tabela, buscando sempre a data mais atual, e transformando em um inteiro?